# Run ctest from a custom dir

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ctest

I have a project containing some unit test code using a template file as a resource.
So I have something like this :

```cpp
std::ofstream out { "../templates/file.cpp" };
```

But depending on where I run the unit tests it does not work.
I use these commands :

```
cd _build
cmake ../src
make -j 4
ctest
```

Is it possible to manage properly resources with cmake (as we can do with Qt) ?
Or is it possible to specify to ctest the run directory ?
I tried the `--build-run-dir` option like this :

```
ctest --build-run-dir ..
```

but the argument is not working.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[add_test](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) has an optional parameter `WORKING_DIRECTORY` that allows you to specify the working directory for a test. That should allow you to correctly specify the path to the template file from within the unit test code.

Quoting from the manual:

> `WORKING_DIRECTORY`
>
> Set the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` test property to specify the working directory in which to execute the test. If not specified the test will
>   be run with the current working directory set to the build directory
>   corresponding to the current source directory.